# How to set views pager item size programmatically?

Tags: views, 8

I want to set views pager size programmatically. I have tried below code to set pager size.

```
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('english_chart');
$view->pager['items_per_page'] = 5;
$view->execute();
```

It's not working and showing this error:

ResponseText: Error: Cannot use object of type Drupal\views\Plugin\views\pager\Some as array ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object returned from `$views->pager` is an object implementing [`ViewsPluginInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21ViewsPluginInterface.php/interface/ViewsPluginInterface/8.2.x) and extending [`PagerPluginBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21pager%21PagerPluginBase.php/class/PagerPluginBase/8.2.x).

If you look at the methods in [`PagerPluginBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21pager%21PagerPluginBase.php/class/PagerPluginBase/8.2.x) you will see the [`setItemsPerPage`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21pager%21PagerPluginBase.php/function/PagerPluginBase%3A%3AsetItemsPerPage/8.2.x) method.

So you should be able to do something like:

```
$view->pager->setItemsPerPage(5);
```