# How to disable views pager programatically in certain cases

Tags: views, 8, paragraphs

I have a paragraph which shows a view. The editor may set some options as argument filters, sort and show/hide pager. "Normal" fields are used to collect these options and `template_preprocess_paragraph__PARAGRAPH_TYPE` actually builds the view. The filtering works well, but I am not able to get rid of the pager if the editor desires to disable it while limiting the amount of items shown at the same time (`$view->setItemsPerPage(0);` is not an option here). Here is some simplified code from mytheme.theme:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph__content_list(&$variables) {
  $view = Views::getView('content_list');
  if (!$view) {
    return;
  }

  // Simulate user input:
  $order = 'DESC';
  $disable_pager = TRUE;
  $items_per_page = 12;
  $filter_args = [1,2,3,4];


  $display_id = 'embed_content_list_title';
  $view->setDisplay($display_id);
  $view->setHandlerOption($display_id, 'sort', 'title', 'order', $order);

  if ($disable_pager) {
    $display = $view->getDisplay();
    $pager = [
      'type' => 'none',
      'options' => [
        'offset' => 0,
        'items_per_page' => 50,
      ],
    ];
    // This doesn't work:
    $display->setOption('pager', $pager);
    $display->setOverride('pager', $pager);
    // This neither works:
    $view->display_handler->setOption('pager', $pager);
    $view->display_handler->setOverride('pager', $pager);
    // I also had no luck with:
    $view->pager = NULL;

    $view->setItemsPerPage($items_per_page);
  }

  $view->execute();
  $variables['content']['content_list'] = $view->buildRenderable($display_id, [$filter_args]);
}
```

How can the pager be disabled in above code? A workaround might be using different displays, one with pager enabled and another with pager disabled. But I would prefer to solve it with just one display (as I already have multiple displays and would have to build both versions for each display).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piggybacking off [How to set views pager item size programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/269652/27710) and looking at [PagerPluginBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21pager%21PagerPluginBase.php/class/PagerPluginBase/8.2.x).

To change values

```
if ($disable_pager == FALSE) {
  $view->setOffset(0);
  $view->setItemsPerPage($items_per_page);
}
```

---

Now to answer your question

> How can the pager be disabled in above code?

You can disable it by setting items per page to zero.

```
$view->setItemsPerPage(0);
```

If you want to limit the amount of items without pager, all you have to do is unset it.

```
   $view = Views::getView('content_list');
   $display_id = 'embed_content_list';
   $view->setDisplay($display_id);
   $view->setItemsPerPage(12);
   $view->execute();
   unset($view->pager); // must put this unset after the $view->execute();
   $variables['content']['content_list'] = $view->buildRenderable($display_id, [$filter_args]);
```

Comment: Thanks @no-sssweat for your answer. `if ($view->pager) {$view->pager->setItemsPerPage(0);}` didn't work. `$view->setItemsPerPage();` works to disable the pager but shows all items, what is not desired, the editor still should be able to limit the amount of items to show but disable the pager. It was my fault, the question was vague about that, so I modified it.

Comment: @LarS try `$view->pager->$total_items = 12;`

Comment: `$view->pager == null` do I need to call something else before? I did:
`$view = Views::getView('content_list');
$display_id = 'embed_content_list';
$view->setDisplay($display_id);
if ($view->pager) {
      $view->pager->setItemsPerPage(0);
      $view->pager->total_items = 50;
}
`

Comment: @LarS I finally tried this myself rather than best guess. Updated my answer.

Comment: Unsetting pager between execute and build works fine, thank you @no-sssweat,